# 67 67 67 : use 3, 67's use any way how to get 11222

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I need to get **11222** using three 67 s (Sixty seven)

We can use any operation in any maner

**67 67 67**

**`use 3,  67's use any way but to get 11222.`**

Answer (score 7):

I'd guess this is a trick question around "using three, sixty-sevens" to get $11222$.

In particular, $67 + 67 = 134$, which is $11222$ in ternary (base $3$).