# Looking for comic about mathematics teacher

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Apologies if this question is considered off-topic on this forum.

Somewhere in the 1990s, I saw a comic (newspaper comic, but I don't remember which newspaper) about a mathematics teacher. His school had advertised that pupils on their school receive only A's; the teacher however had given one pupil an A-minus, for writing something like '5+5=11', upon which he is sued by the pupil. The comic then goes on to show how the school chooses side with the pupil, how the teacher ends up in court, being crushed by the pupil's advocate, by the press, etc.

Does anyone remember this comic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comics to which you refer are from Garry Trudeau's *Doonesbury*. The first comic relevant to your question was printed on December 20, 1993, and they continued through January 1, 1994.

[Here](http://www.gocomics.com/doonesbury/1993/12/20) is a link to the first relevant comic, after which you can search for whichever one(s) you'd like. The image quality is not great, but this should help you locate what you need.

Comment: FWIW: This is the toughest question I've answered since http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232800/67-67-67-use-3-67s-use-any-way-how-to-get-11222/

Comment: At least your initials are appropriate for the comic :-)

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you so much! How did you find the answer? (Or did you happen to remember it?)

Comment: @user60213 Never read the comic (and was only 7 when those strips were published). I somehow googled my way to http://www.bus.lsu.edu/accounting/faculty/lcrumbley/study.htm which has a paragraph beginning: "Garry Trudeau’s comic strip..." After seeing that, I looked up the archives for *Doonesbury* and sped through December 1993. Question to answer took about five minutes, but only after years of honing my querying skills.

Comment: May we know what terms you Googled for?

Comment: BTW (also FWIW), the story continues on 21 Feb 1994, with the teacher's lawyer appearing on TV, and a court session.

Comment: Also FWIW, my favorite episodes are those of 8 March and 9 March.

Comment: @user60213 I googled: **"comic strip" "mathematics" "lawsuit" "A minus"**